# Ошибка при импорте, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named *моя папка проекта*"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Visual Studio Code никаких ошибок не выдает, только Python при запуске `main.py`.

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Sarcandi\Python\SarOS Bots\saros_bot\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import saros_bot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'saros_bot'
```

Структура проекта:

[image: 1]

Код `main.py`:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.filters import Command
from asyncio import run
from logging import basicConfig, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, CRITICAL
from saros_bot import test_bot_token as token, start_handler, comment_handler, clear_keyboard_handler, manage_db_handler, AntiFloodMiddleware

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher()

async def start() -> None:
    dp.message.middleware(AntiFloodMiddleware())
    dp.message.register(start_handler, Command('start'))
    dp.message.register(manage_db_handler, Command('manage_db'))
    dp.message.register(clear_keyboard_handler, Command('clear_keyboard'))
    dp.message.register(comment_handler, F.chat.id == -1001234567890)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    basicConfig(level=DEBUG)
    run(start())
```

Код `__init__.py`:

```
from saros_bot.data.secret_data import main_bot_token, test_bot_token, admins_id, SarcandiID, SarOS_Bot_News_id
from saros_bot.files.functions.database_functions import manage_db_function
from saros_bot.files.handlers.handlers import start_handler, comment_handler, clear_keyboard_handler, manage_db_handler
from saros_bot.files.keyboards.inline_keyboards import subscribe_SarOS_Bot_News_inline_keyboard, database_inline_keyboard
from saros_bot.files.keyboards.reply_keyboards import clear_reply_keyboard, main_menu_reply_keyboard
from saros_bot.files.middlewares.middlewares import AntiFloodMiddleware, CheckSubscriptionMiddleware
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задал тот же вопрос на [Хабр Q&A](https://qna.habr.com).
Там человек написал [решение](https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=2394680), цитирую:

> Проблема в том, что ты пытаешься сделать бота и скриптом, и модулем. А импорт работает только одним способом.
> Я бы сказал, просто вынеси main в папку выше (ну или остального бота в подпапку).
> Тогда бот будет модулем, а главный скрипт - скриптом.
>
> Не, ты, конечно, можешь в `__init__` написать изврат в духе
>
> ```py
> try:
>     from .wtf import stuff
> except ImportError:
>     from wtf import stuff
> ```
>
> И сделать в main `from __init__ import *`
> Но не надо так делать. Пожалеешь потом.

В итоге решил перенести папку `data` в `files`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, ваш файл main.py находится в папке saros_bot. Если это так, то вам нужно импортировать модули напрямую из папки. Например:

**было**: `from saros_bot.data.secret_data import main_bot_token, test_bot_token, admins_id, SarcandiID, SarOS_Bot_News_id`

**стало**: `from data.secret_data import main_bot_token, test_bot_token, admins_id, SarcandiID, SarOS_Bot_News_id`

Надеюсь вам это поможет.

Comment: До того как я создал __init__.py так и было, потом решил создать __init__.py, и импортировать с его помощью, и в итоге возникла такая ошибка. Возможно просто верну как было и уберу __init__.py